# Define compilation variables based on target for

Tags: makefile

my c++ source file look for a specific variable passed from the makefile.  when making a different target, this variable definition is different.

How can I define a variable in Makefile based on target.

Thanks

Comment: The variable is being passed as `-D` flag? Can you please provide an excerpt from your Makefile with several targets in question?

Answer (score 17):

You can use [target-specific variable values](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific), they propagate to target's prerequisites:

```
all : foo bar
foo : CXXFLAGS += -DFOO
bar : CXXFLAGS += -DBAR

foo bar :
    @echo target=$@ CXXFLAGS=${CXXFLAGS}

.PHONY : all
```

Comment: @martinkunev Well, GNU make is the only portable make, AFAIK. `nmake` is Windows specific and is rubbish, Sun make circles down the drain with the Sun and Solaris... I am not familiar with other makes.

Answer (score 10):

Do you mean something like this:

```
$ cat Makefile
BUILD := debug

cxxflags.debug := -g -march=native
cxxflags.release := -g -O3 -march=native -DNDEBUG
CXXFLAGS := ${cxxflags.${BUILD}}

all :
    @echo BUILD=${BUILD}
    @echo CXXFLAGS=${CXXFLAGS}

.PHONY : all
```

Output:

```
$ make
BUILD=debug
CXXFLAGS=-g -march=native

$ make BUILD=release
BUILD=release
CXXFLAGS=-g -O3 -march=native -DNDEBUG
```

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for,

Answer (score 0):

What about that?

```
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),release)
    CFLAGS += -O3
else
    CFLAGS += -O0 -ggdb
endif
```