# How can I set the value of a variable in a makefile depending on a MAKEFLAG?

Tags: if-statement, makefile, gnu-make

My makefile is compiling my program for debugging. By that I mean that it passes `-g -D DEBUG` to the compiler. I want to be able to pass `-nd` for **n**ot **d**ebug or `-p` for **p**roduction to make thus removing the debug flags from the compiler. To do this I'd need some way of putting this into make syntax: *"If MAKEFLAGS is not **nd** then set CFLAGS to `-g -D DEBUG` otherwise leave it empty"*

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127977/makefile-define-compilation-variables-based-on-target-for/5153406#5153406

Comment: No you mean "is not 'nd'", or "does not contain 'nd' or 'p'"?

Comment: `MAKEFLAGS` is a make built-in variable? Do you mean `MAKEFLAGS` or do you mean some other, project specific, variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you care about is `-nd`, this will do it:

```
ifeq (,$(findstring nd,$(MAKEFLAGS)))
FOO = -g -D DEBUG
endif
```

If you also care about `-p`, it's not quite as clean:

```
FOO = -g -D DEBUG
ifneq (,$(findstring nd,$(MAKEFLAGS)))
FOO =
endif

ifneq (,$(findstring p,$(MAKEFLAGS)))
FOO =
endif
```

Comment: The `$(findstring nd,...)` bit will also trigger if `make --warn-undefined-variables` is passed (when using `$(MAKEFLAGS)` for this as opposed to some other, custom, variable).

Comment: @EtanReisner: Good point. I'd try to bullet-proof it, but it doesn't look as if many people are interested in this question.

Comment: This detail is actually somewhat annoying since the manual gets it wrong too (in section 7.3).