# gnu make : how to make conditional cflags

Tags: mingw, gnu-make

I started a simple makefile for my project (MS-windows target, MinGW) with the following :

```
CFLAGS = -g -O0 -Wall -std=c99

CC =    gcc
CPP =   g++
LIBS =

PBDUMPER = pbdumper.exe

all: $(PBDUMPER)

$(PBDUMPER): pbdumper.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(PBDUMPER)

.PHONY: clean
```

Now I would like to choose between release and debug compilation.
I have changed the variable definitions and implicit rule for debug :

```
CFLAGS_COMMON = -std=c99
CFLAGS_DEBUG = -g -O0 -Wall
CFLAGS_RELEASE = -O2 -Wall
...
$(PBDUMPER): pbdumper.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_COMMON) $(CFLAGS_DEBUG) -o $@ $< $(LIBS)
```

But for release I would have to change the implicit rule to use the CFLAGS_RELEASE which is I suppose the wrong way to do.
I have looked at the Gnu Make manual in the "implicit rules" and "automatic variables" sections but I did not found a better way.

Could you show me the correct way, by either conditionally defining the CFLAGS, or maybe using a "if" in the implicit rules based on the flavour selected for compilation ? Or maybe another method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127977/makefile-define-compilation-variables-based-on-target-for/5153406#5153406

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: nice solution, I did searched for similar questions before asking, but I did not found your answer.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: I have adopted your solution, thanks :)

Comment: Good to know. I like that solution, it's clean and scales well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of archiving the solution and not keeping a question unanswered, here is the final word :
following [Maxim's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127977/makefile-define-compilation-variables-based-on-target-for/5153406#5153406), I have reworked my Makefile as :

```
#debug is default, for another flavor : make BUILD=release
BUILD := debug

cflags.common := -std=c99
cflags.debug := -g -O0 -Wall
cflags.release := -O2 -Wall
CFLAGS := ${cflags.${BUILD}} ${cflags.common}
LIBS =

CC =    gcc
CPP =   g++

#executable
PBDUMPER = pbdumper.exe

all: $(PBDUMPER)

$(PBDUMPER): pbdumper.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(PBDUMPER)

.PHONY: clean all
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be a simple comment/uncomment solution:

```
CFLAGS = -std=c99
# Release
# CFLAGS += -O2 -Wall
# Debug
CFLAGS += -g -O0 -Wall
```

This is how automake does this type of configuration. You could also use a make conditional
around these lines:

```
ifeq ($(build),release)
    CFLAGS += -O2 -Wall
else
    CFLAGS += -g -O0 -Wall
endif
```

In general, be careful with such schemes because you absolutely have to clean out old object files on release. Two-tree builds with autoconf and automake (or a simple hand-rolled configure) are more reliable, even though a little harder to set up.

Comment: The first option seems quite simple indeed. I was not aware of the `+=` operator for make variables. But for the second possibilty, where would the $build value come from ? Defined on the command line ?

Comment: @Seki: For example, or at the top of the Makefile.

Comment: ok. Take a look at the answer proposed by Maxim in the comments. It has the benefit for not needing to change the makefile to change the makefile for changing the build type, and last but not least : it does not imply the autotools (which I do not want to cope with for producing my simple 1-module tool ;)