# c++ linking and compiling flags

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, g++, flags

I may have a stupid question but as no question is stupid i'll ask it... let's imagine i have the files `matrix.hpp` and `matrix.cpp`. In those files i use `assert(...)` to make sure that some condition is respected. I compile this file and get a `matrix.o` file. Now i will use this `matrix.o` file in many different programs, some of them are only tests and need to check the `assert(...)` conditions, others are working programs that don't need these checks.

My question is : can i compile the `matrix.o` without the `-DNDEBUG` flag, thus in general, the `assert(...)` condition will be checked. but when i link the .o files for a program which doesn't need the checks, i add this flag without recompiling the `matrix.o` file.

To be more precise, would this do what i want :

```
# the test program with the "assert(..)" checks    
test:test.o matrix.o
    gcc -o $@ $^
test.o:test.cpp matrix.hpp
    gcc -c $^

# the real program without the "assert(..)" checks
prog:prog.o matrix.o
    gcc -o $@ $^ -DNDEBUG
prog.o:prog.cpp matrix.hpp
    gcc -c -DNDEBUG $^

# the matrix.o that can be either checked or not if the -DNDEBUG flag
# is given when the .o files are linked
matrix.o:matrix.cpp matrix.hpp
    gcc -c $^
```

ok thank you for your answer ! So i can't do that simply using the flags -DNDEBUG. What if each time i use "assert(...)" in the matrix files i add :

```
#ifdef CHECK
assert(...) 
#endif
```

and now when i compile the "test" program i use a CHECK flag but not with the "prog" program ? I guess it won't work either...

Comment: Two questions I think are relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035394/gnu-make-how-to-make-conditional-cflags
which in turns references http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127977/makefile-define-compilation-variables-based-on-target-for/5153406#5153406

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is **no**.  Depending on your exact circumstances there might be some clever tricks you can pull (e.g. linking in a different "assert failed" function).

Have you considered throwing an exception instead of asserting?  Then, 'prog' and 'test' could take different approaches to handling it.

Comment: PS:  Obviously(?), any asserts in functions defined in matrix.hpp (assuming that is #include-d by prog.cpp and test.cpp) will work the way you want.

Comment: thanks ! yes i considered throwing an exception but i don't want to do that because of the increasing runtime cost...

Answer (score 0):

No, not with GCC. I see two options:

1. compile two versions of `matrix.o` and link the appropriate version into each program, or
2. replace `assert` with a manual check that throws an exception.

The latter option obviously has some runtime cost even in the non-test programs, so use it with care (not inside an inner loop).