# Writing a makefile to use -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG in debug build

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I have a makefile that can be reduced to this:

```
OBJS = obj1.o obj2.o

FLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors -fno-rtti -std=c++0x
DEBUG_FLAGS = -ggdb -O0 -fstack-protector-all -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG
RELEASE_FLAGS = -O3

release: $(OBJS)
    g++ $(FLAGS) $(RELEASE_FLAGS) $(OBJS)

debug: $(OBJS)
    g++ $(FLAGS) $(DEBUG_FLAGS) $(OBJS)

obj1.o: obj1.cpp
    g++ -c $(FLAGS) obj1.cpp

obj2.o: obj2.cpp
    g++ -c $(FLAGS) obj2.cpp
```

The problem is that all or none of the files must be built with the `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` flag. I don't know how to do this without writing two entries for every compilation unit, like

```
obj1_release.o: obj1.cpp
    g++ -c $(FLAGS) $(RELEASE_FLAGS) obj1.cpp

obj1_debug.o: obj1.cpp
    g++ -c $(FLAGS) $(DEBUG_FLAGS) obj1.cpp
```

How can I make the `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` flag (and the other debug flags) take effect for all compilation units only when the user types `make debug` without writing two entries for every CU? (And vice versa; the release flags need to take effect on all CUs when the user types `make release`.)

I apologise if this is the basics of writing Makefiles, I don't know much about them.

Comment: You don't need those dollar signs on the lines that *define* the Make variables.

Comment: @Zack whoops, yeah I mistyped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html): something like this should do what you want.  Note that this *cannot* be made to work correctly unless the debug and release versions of the program are given different names.

```
OBJS   := obj1 obj2 obj3
R_OBJS := $(OBJS:=_r.o)
D_OBJS := $(OBJS:=_d.o)

all: prog_r prog_d
release: prog_r
debug: prog_d

prog_r: $(R_OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(RELEASE_FLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS) -o $@

prog_d: $(D_OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(DEBUG_FLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS) -o $@

%_r.o: %.cc
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(RELEASE_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%_d.o: %.cc
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(DEBUG_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# header files
obj1_d.o obj1_r.o: foo.h bar.h
obj2_d.o obj2_r.o: quux.h
# ... etc ...
```

Comment: Was `D_OBJS := $(OBJS:-_d.o)` supposed to be `D_OBJS := $(OBJS:=_d.o)`, or was the `-` supposed to only be there for `D_OBJS` but not for `R_OBJS`?

Comment: That's a typo; it was supposed to be `=` in both cases.  Will fix.

Comment: So how do you do the dependencies for each .cc file? For example, I have some headers that some .cc files depend on and some do not. I have them marked as dependencies for the files that use them so that they will be recompiled when the headers are modified, but they are not dependencies for the files that don't use them. It seems like this method makes all the .cc files have exactly the same prerequisites (namely the .cc file it's compiling), or am I missing something?

Comment: Those are properly dependencies of the `.o` files, not the `.cc` files (you don't have to regenerate the *source code* when you change the headers, eh?)  You can list them in rules without commands, and the pattern rules will still apply.  I'll add an example.

Comment: If you have more than ten object files, you probably don't want to keep the header-file dependencies up to date by hand -- at that point, invest in learning [automake](http://www.gnu.org/s/automake), which will arrange to generate them as a side effect of compilation.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to _prepend_ a name to the .o files instead of _append_ it? For instance, instead of all the object files ending in `_d` for the debug versions, I want them to begin with `debug_`.

Comment: Yes, just write `debug_%.o` instead of `%_d.o`.  You'll also need to change the variable definitions to use a written-out [`patsubst`](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Text-Functions.html) expression, like `D_OBJS := $(patsubst %,debug_%.o,$(OBJS))`; the shorthand `$(OBJS:x=y)` notation only works for suffixes.

Comment: Yeah I knew about the other one, it was `D_OBJS := whatever` that I was asking about. Thanks.

Comment: I take that last back: `$(OBJS:%=debug_%.o)` [should work too](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Substitution-Refs.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is a [pretty straightforward way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5153406/412080) to select compilation flags based on the type of the build in Makefiles.

In addition to that you may like to ensure that debug build only links debug object files and same for release (i.e. no mixing debug and release object files). To achieve that compile object into different directories depending on the build type.

Answer (score 0):

This might help : http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/make-3.79/html_chapter/make_7.html

You could check the first argument (debug/release) and set the CFLAGS accordingly.

HTH.