# How do I disable GCC optimization when using makefiles?

Tags: c++, linux, optimization, gcc, makefile

I've just started learning Linux and I'm having some trouble disabling GCC's optimization for one of my C++ projects.

The project is built with makefiles like so...

```
make -j 10 && make install
```

I've read on various sites that the command to disable optimization is something along the lines of...

```
gcc -O0 <your code files>
```

Could someone please help me apply this to makefiles instead of individual code?  I've been searching for hours and have come up empty handed.

Comment: it's going to be hard to propose edits to a Makefile that we can't see

Comment: -O0 is the default if you don't specify an optimization level. You may want to use the -g flag as this generates debug symbols.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've been quite busy.  Here's one of the makefiles: http://pastebin.com/ftvXEFbv

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In some standard makefile settings you could

```
make -j10 -e CPPFLAGS=-O0
```

But the makefile might use other substitution variables or override the environment. You need to show us the Makefile in order to propose edits

Comment: `CPPFLAGS` often stands for C preprocessor flags, `CXXFLAGS` are the flags for the C++ compiler.

Comment: @Fanael while that may be true, `CPPFLAGS` is usually added to `CXXFLAGS` and `CFLAGS` which makes it the more general entry point.

Comment: @Fanael: The default rule for C++ files is `$(CXX) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS)`

Comment: @sehe: You are making assumptions about the current shell. You should specify the shell you are using as the OP is obviously not fluent in *nix. Also note a simpler way for bash (and family) is `CPPFLAGS=-O0 make -e -j10` as the sets CPPFLAGS only for the current command not in a persistant way that will affect other commands.

Comment: @LokiAstari: What? We are psychic-debugging an entire Makefile out of thin air and you are concerned with assumptions about a shell. I _know that_? :). PS. Make that `make -e CPPFLAGS=-O0` then, anyway, will fix

Comment: You don't need `-e` though, `make` command line variable assignments override those from the makefile.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest (useful) makefile that allows debug/release mode is:

```
#
# Define the source and object files for the executable
SRC     = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ     = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o, $(SRC))

#
# set up extra flags for explicitly setting mode
debug:      CXXFLAGS    += -g
release:    CXXFLAGS    += -O3

#
# Link all the objects into an executable.
all:    $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o example $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)

#
# Though both modes just do a normal build.
debug:      all
release:    all

clean:
    rm $(OBJ)
```

Usage Default build (No specified optimizations)

```
> make
g++    -c -o p1.o p1.cpp
g++    -c -o p2.o p2.cpp
g++ -o example p1.o p2.o
```

Usage: Release build (uses -O3)

```
> make clean release
rm p1.o p2.o
g++ -O3   -c -o p1.o p1.cpp
g++ -O3   -c -o p2.o p2.cpp
g++ -o example p1.o p2.o
```

Usage: Debug build (uses -g)

```
> make clean debug
rm p1.o p2.o
g++ -g   -c -o p1.o p1.cpp
g++ -g   -c -o p2.o p2.cpp
g++ -o example p1.o p2.o
```

Comment: Note, that your target specific variables won't work when a target other than `debug` or `release` specified. A more robust way is http://stackoverflow.com/a/5153406/412080

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: It works fine with no target specified. It is designed to use no variables when you don't specify anything. It will use the first rule `all` which just builds the code. **As Shown Above**. I see no advantage to the makefile you link too. It is definitely **not more** robust.  It just does the same thing using a different technique (except unless you specify something it defaults to -g (which is not what I would want)).

Comment: Right, it won't work for `make this that`, only for `make`, `make debug` and `make release`.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: Exactly. That is a good thing not a bad thing. IT may seem like flexibility is a good thing. But in reality flexibility is bain on robustness.

Comment: This is because `CXXFLAGS` you customize for `debug` and `release` only apply when you build one of these targets. They don't apply if you specify that you want to build one executable out of say 10 you have in total. That's why this way of customizing the build is not robust.

Comment: If you are building 10 executable out of one directory you have other problems in your code organization that go for beyond the problems associated with makefiles :-)

Comment: I build 100 executables and 300 shared libraries using non-recursive make dude. Some sub-projects build 10s of executables and I can build a sub-project only, but sometimes I want to build just one executable. Make a sub-project/directory for each executable would be maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I build many more. And for some strange reason I tend **not** to stick all my source files in the same directory. My make file in each directory looks like this: `TARGET=app <newline> include $(BASE)/Make.global` So each makefile is about two lines long and very easy to maintain.

Comment: Reminds me of: no matter how many you build, i build +1 more. ) If you build many more I'd expect you to get the build flags right...

Comment: Okay, so to build 3 executables only you need to invoke make 3 times, right?

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: I am not super human. I tend to work on one project at a time. When finished I submit it to the build system for validation which builds everything and validates. The maintenance night mare seems not to be the makefile though I am sure it looks horrible but in your whole approach to dumping everything into one directory. You should take a leaf out of the tried and true methods used by any major project. There are pleanty of open source projects out there. They **don't** do it like you and for a good reason. Please take the time and have a look. You may learn something.

Comment: I didn't say all my sources in one directory, but I said "non-recursive make", which is a different thing. Majority of open source projects have poor structure and horrible makefiles. You may like http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin:  That's like saying most car drivers are bad. I agree. But you can still study the best car drivers and improve your own driving technique from them. There are plenty of big open source projects with a good makefile layout.

Answer (score 0):

For example, an optimized compilations can be written as:

```
all:
    g++ -O3 main.cpp
```

A compilation with debug information (no optimization) can be written as:

```
all:
    g++ -g main.cpp
```

Comment: Nobody writes a makefile like that. In fact you don't even need a file for that just type `make main`

Comment: Of course, it's not a usable makefile. Just a minimal example of how to enable/disable optimizations.