# specifying a make variable in a rule

Tags: variables, makefile, gnu

I would like to set a variable $(CFLAGS2) to hold different values depending on  the target i make. Specifically, i want to  have a target which compiles my project with "-g -Wall", and another one which compiles with "-O3"

I tried it like this:

```
CC=gcc
COPT=-c $<  -o $@ $(CADD) $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS2)

.PHONY: opti
.PHONY: debi

opti: seto
    make hammingtest
debi: setd 
    make hammingtest

.PHONY: seto
seto: 
    $(eval CFLAGS2 := -O3)

.PHONY: setd
setd: 
    $(eval CFLAGS2 :=-g -Wall)

hamming.o: hamming.cpp hamming.h
    $(CC) $(COPT) $(DEFS) $(CFLAGS2)

hammingtest.o: hammingtest.cpp hamming.h
    $(CC) $(COPT) $(DEFS) $(CFLAGS2)

hammingtest: hammingtest.o hamming.o
    $(CC)  -o hammingtest hammingtest.o hamming.o
```

But when i do "make debi" it acts as if $(CFLAGS") was not set at all (the same with "make opti")
How can i achieve this?

Comment: Oli: thanks for editing

Comment: I found the solution but i haven't found out how to create an answer here in which i can display code (i.e. not a comment)...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Makefile - define compilation variables based on target for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127977/makefile-define-compilation-variables-based-on-target-for)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `$(eval ...)` in shell lines. That is usually just plain wrong.

There is a number of ways to do what you want. Since you already have recursive make set up, you could use command-line variables:

```
opti:
    ${MAKE} COPTS2='-O3' hammingtest

debi:
    ${MAKE} COPTS2='-g -Wall' hammingtest
```

A better style is to eschew the recursive make, maybe in favour of target specific variables:

```
CC=gcc
COPT=-c $<  -o $@ $(CADD) $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS2)

CFLAGS2 = $(error Someone tried to deref CFLAGS2!)
opti: CFLAGS2 := -O3
debi: CFLAGS2 := -g -Wall

.PHONY: all
all:
    @echo 'What do you want to make?'

.PHONY: opti debi
opti debi: hammingtest
opti debi: ; @echo $@ Success

.
.
.
```

This looks likely to work at a cursory glance.

The way this is set up though is problematic. For example, the following sequence of shell commands will give you an optimised build, with no warnings.

```
$ make opti
$ make debi
```