# Calling make with two targets

Tags: makefile

I have C++ project that I build using a Makefile with two targets as so

```
debug: FLAGS += -g3 -DDEBUG -DSOCKET_LOG_COMMUNICATION
    @printf ""

test: some_other_target
    $(COMPILER) ...
```

I wanted to call make as so

```
make debug test
```

to define a macro and also build the test target.  Is this possible?

Comment: Why not simply having another target `debug-test` that depends on both?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That is what I have at the moment!  I was just wondering if this was possible

Comment: A good way to implement different compile modes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5153406/412080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target-specific variables apply only to the named target and its dependencies (unless the variable is declared `private`), so the only way you would be able to have `test` inherit `debug`'s variables would be `debug: test` which probably isn't what you're looking for.

One way to do this is use conditional statements:

```
ifdef debug
FLAGS += -g3 -DDEBUG -DSOCKET_LOG_COMMUNICATION
$(info whatever)
endif

test: some_other_target
    $(COMPILER) ...
```

and invoke `make test debug=1`.